# How do you calculate average absolute value of a sum of sin functions with different amplitudes and frequencies?

Tags: voltage, math, sine

I cant seem to find the answer anywhere. I remember there was a simple formula for doing this but I dont have the book with it anymore. Finding where the function is positive and where is negative and than integrating it would be too tedious.

Comment: Average implies a temporal behaviour, so you have to first determine what period you want to use for averaging. Then, if it's continuous time, you do a definite integration, if it's sampled, you do an average of the samples in that time interval. You don't need to find where the function is positive or negative, all you're interested in is the average, which can be positive or negative.

Comment: @ a concerned citizen Im looking for average of absolute values though

Comment: It doesn't matter what function you have or what sort of result you want, you have to have some kind of integration, continuous or discrete, in order to *average* a quantity.

Comment: @a concerned citizen So when you want to find the effective value of sinusidal voltage you can just calculate it by dividing its max value with square root of 2. When you more than one function superimposed you just take square root of the sum of sqares of effective values. There is anoter formula for doing it for averages of absolute values and Im looking for that. I know you have to integrate to find the averages.

Comment: Are you referring to the formula for calculating the [THD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_harmonic_distortion)?